# NodeJS unable to modify a class obj

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

this is my first post in this forum. So please forgive me the misstakes.

I want to write a NodeJS server which runs a WebSocket Server (npm ws module).
The NodeJS server contains also a Class Obj which i want to modify a funciton afterwards over the Websocket server.
My Problem is the modified functjion cant acces global variables.

Can someone help if there is a solution for this problem or why this happes because if you do this without the Websocket it works.

Here is the code:

Server code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');


// WebSocket Server
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        try {
            message = JSON.parse(message);
            if (message.type == "handler") {
                handler.modify(message.data);
                console.log("modifyed");
            }
            if (message.type == "func") {
                handler.modify_func(message.data);
                console.log("modifyed");
            }
            if (message.type == "run") {
                eval(message.data);
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
        }
    });
});

// Modifying class
class Handler {
    constructor() {
        this.functions = [];
    }

    modify(data) {
        let temp_class = new Function('return ' + data)();

        temp_class.functions.forEach(element => {
            if (this.functions.indexOf(element) == -1) {
                this.functions.push(element)
            }
            this[element] = temp_class[element];
        });
    }

    modify_func(data) {
        let temp_func = new Function('return ' + data)();
        this[temp_func.name] = temp_func;
    }

    test_func_from_orginal() {
        console.log("test_func_from_orginal says:");
        console.log(test_val);
    }

}


var test_val = "this is the global variable";
var handler = new Handler();
```

Client code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');


//WebSocket Client
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
ws.on('open', function open(event) {
    // ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "handler", data: Handler.toString() }))
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "func", data: test_func_from_func.toString() }))
    console.log("open")
});

//Class Module
class Handler {
    static get functions() {
        return ["test"];
    }
    static test_func_from_class() {
        console.log("test_func_from_class sayes:")
        console.log(test_val);
    }
}


function test_func_from_func() {
    console.log("test_func_from_func sayes:")
    console.log(test_val);
}




setTimeout(function () { ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "run", data: 'handler.test_func_from_orginal()' })) }, 1000);
// setTimeout(function () { ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "run", data: 'handler.test_func_from_class()' })) }, 1000);
setTimeout(function () { ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "run", data: 'handler.test_func_from_func()' })) }, 1000);
```

Comment: Why  do you allow modifying the engine like that? Not only it's completely unsafe, but also totally error-prone, and not being able to scope the access properly is only a small chunk of problems you might have. Could you describe what exactly you're trying to do here?

Comment: I want to change the handler live without restarting the server. Because the server must run permanently.      - Thanks for the fast comment

Comment: The server will never run *permanently*, and architecture of your system should never depend on that. Servers go down, regardless of whether they're hosted on premises or within a cloud. What you're trying to do - a hot reload system - is still considered experimental even for development purposes, as there's a lot of issues to solve when trying to make the changes transactional.

Comment: So there is no realy a solution for this problem?

Comment: You'll need to reorganize your server, splitting the state (data that gets passed to/from websockets) and storing at least some part of it outside the server (persisting). This way when the server goes down, you'll be able to restore. Not only that; this also makes your system more scalable (as you will hit the wall trying to manage this data inside a single machine).

Comment: I mean, technically the solution you've prepared does work, there was a simple mistake (and the answer shows how it works). But the whole approach is flaky, so it's better to rework it until the system grows and it'll be much harder to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is what it's all about - a simple mistake. If you cut out all the websocket stuff (which is not really relevant here, as strings, and not contexts, got passed from and back anyway), you'll get this:

```
class ServerHandler {
    constructor() {
        this.functions = [];
    }

    modify(data) {
        let temp_class = new Function('return ' + data)();
        // not sure why not just `eval(data)` btw

        temp_class.functions.forEach(funcName => {
            if (this.functions.indexOf(funcName) == -1) {
                this.functions.push(funcName)
            }
            this[funcName] = temp_class[funcName];
        });
    }
}

class ClientHandler {
    static get functions() {
        return ["test_func_from_class"]; 
        // not "test" as in your example

        // you actually don't even need this registry: 
        // all the static methods can be collected in runtime
    }
    static test_func_from_class() {
        console.log("test_func_from_class sayes:")
        console.log(test_val);
    }
}

var test_val = 42;
var handler = new ServerHandler();

handler.modify(ClientHandler.toString());
eval(`handler.test_func_from_class()`); // 42
```

This all works fine, as there's no longer a mismatch between a name of method stored in static get functions ("test") and actual name of that method ("test_func_from_class"). The trick is that all the static functions created along with that temporary class are scoped the same way any other entity created in ServerHandler; that's how they 'see' that `test_val`.

But 'works' here is about mere possibility of this approach from technical perspective, and not about feasibility. Both `new Function` and `eval` with arbitrary input are very dangerous security holes - and they're left wide open here.

Answer (score 0):

I found now a solution for my problem.

Server Code

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');




// WebSocket Server
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        message = JSON.parse(message);
        try {
            if (message.type == "run") {
                eval(message.data);
            }
            if (message.type == "obj_handler") {

                handler.modify(JSON.parse(message.data));
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        // console.log('received: %s', message);
    });

    ws.send('something');
});




class ServerHandler {
    constructor() {
        this.data = "hi";
    }
    modify(data) {
        for (const func in data) {
        this[func] = eval(data[func]);
        }
    }
}

var test_val = 42;
var handler = new ServerHandler();
```

Client Code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');



//WebSocket Client
try {
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    ws.on('open', function open(event) {
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "obj_handler", data: update.convert() }))

    });
}
catch (error) {

}




// Needed Update with 2 new Functions
update = {
    func_test_global: () => {
        console.log(test_val);
    },


    func_test_this: _ => {
        console.log(this.data);

    },
    convert: function () {
        let new_update = {};

        for (const func in this) {
            if (func != "convert")
                new_update[func] = "" + this[func];
        }
        return JSON.stringify(new_update)
    }
}


// setTimeout(function () { ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "run", data: 'handler.func_test_global()' })) }, 1000);
// setTimeout(function () { ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "run", data: 'handler.func_test_this()' })) }, 1000);
```